# Jellyfin is not starting. code=dumped, signal=ABRT

Tags: software-installation

Jellyfin is not starting.I got this error[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6et6X.png). I'm running jellyfin on ubuntu server. Please help me.

```
"Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2024-02-26 14:12:04 UTC; 47min ago
    Process: 29836 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jellyfin (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
   Main PID: 29836 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)"
```

I ran this command `sudo journalctl -ru jellyfin` and found:

```
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: Stopped Jellyfin Media Server.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.StartApp(StartupOptions options)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.CreateApplicationPaths(StartupOptions option>
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]: Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/jellyfin' is denied.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.StartApp(StartupOptions options)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at Jellyfin.Server.Program.CreateApplicationPaths(StartupOptions option>
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]:  ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/jellyfin' is denied.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver jellyfin[1255]: Unhandled Exception
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: Started Jellyfin Media Server.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: Stopped Jellyfin Media Server.
Feb 27 01:56:23 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 27 01:56:22 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
Feb 27 01:56:22 darpanserver systemd[1]: jellyfin.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
```

Comment: You can get more logging information by running `sudo journalctl -ru jellyfin` Please run this and add the logs from the last run to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that the /var/log/jellyfin directory is missing,  check whether this directory exists or whether it has drwxr-xr-x 2 root root access rights

Comment: The directory is exist and It has root:root access rights :

"drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Feb 26 12:38 /var/log/jellyfin"

Comment: @Darpan What you copy-pasted in there does not match the access rights given in the above answer - looking at the last three slots, indicating the access rights that "everyone" (neither owner nor group) have, the answer above shows that "everyone" should have read and execute rights, while it seems that directory on your system is inaccessible to anyone other than root (unless there are ACLs in use). May be worth checking.